# unexpected '$fridays' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting syntax error in the following code:

```
function getFridays($year='', $format='', $timezone = 'UTC') {

$fridays = array();
$startDate = new DateTime("{$year}-01-01 Friday", new DateTimezone($timezone));

$year++;
$endDate = new DateTime("{$year}-01-01", new DateTimezone($timezone));

$int = new DateInterval('P7D');

foreach (new DatePeriod($startDate, $int, $endDate) as $d) {
    $fridays[] = $d->format($format);

}

return $fridays;
}

$fridays = getFridays($year, 'Y-m-d', 'America/New_York');
```

> Error: unexpected '$fridays' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: And on codeigniter `$this->getFridays($year, 'Y-m-d', 'America/New_York')` if on a controller

Comment: add your entire class because if i copy your code to a sandbox its working perfectly fine as you can see here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2d7fc79f19389cc9a5a2379ad546230c56bd8a0d

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this line

```
$fridays = getFridays($year, 'Y-m-d', 'America/New_York');
```

You cannot put this outside of the function and called another function. If you want to call this you have to put it in another function. Just try to `var_dump` the `$friday` after the return outside of the for loop.

```
var_dump($friday);
exit;
```

you can see your array.

Comment: his function is perfectly fine... (http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2d7fc79f19389cc9a5a2379ad546230c56bd8a0d)

Comment: @sintakonte yeah it perfectly fines but i think he is using codeigniter because of codeigniter tag. In codeigniter if you are in controller you cannot have function like this. Thats why i assume.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code works fine is copied directly into a sandbox because all of the class stuff is missing. Without it, it will work fine. So, you're declaring the variable inside a method, but trying to set it outside of the method, which is a no-go.